# How to make slant lines for rows in html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[image]

I want to know how to add slant row starting and ending in HTML and css.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you are looking for is called slopy elements. Here's a nice snippet from [tympanus.net](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/21/slopy-elements-with-css3/)

```css
.se-container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.se-slope {
  margin: 0 -50px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  -ms-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.se-slope:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  margin-top: -200px;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.se-slope:nth-child(even) {
  background: #e90089;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
}

.se-content {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.se-content h3 {
  font-size: 60px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px 8px 30px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #000;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: 'Bitter', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.se-content h3:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 38px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: -59px;
  top: 0px;
}

.se-content h3:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 38px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  right: -59px;
  top: 0px;
}

.se-slope:nth-child(odd) .se-content h3:before,
.se-slope:nth-child(odd) .se-content h3:after {
  border-right-color: #e90089;
  border-left-color: #e90089;
}

.se-content p {
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.se-content p:first-letter {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Adobe Garamond Pro', Garamond, Palatino, 'Palatino Linotype', Times, 'Times New Roman', Georgia, serif;
}

.se-slope:nth-child(odd) .se-content {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  color: #e90089;
  padding: 130px 100px 250px 100px;
}

.se-slope:nth-child(even) .se-content {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  color: #000;
  padding: 150px 100px 250px 100px;
}

.se-slope:nth-child(odd) .se-content h3 {
  background: #e90089;
  color: #000;
}

.se-slope:nth-child(even) .se-content h3 {
  background: #000;
  color: #e90089;
}


/* Media Queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 1010px) {
  .se-content h3 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .se-content h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .se-content h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 60px;
  }
  .se-content p {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .se-slope:nth-child(odd) .se-content,
  .se-slope:nth-child(even) .se-content {
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <section class="se-container">
    <div class="se-slope">
      <article class="se-content">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <p>LOL LOL LOL LOL
        </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="se-slope">
      <article class="se-content">
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <p>LOL LOL LOL LOL </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="se-slope">
      <article class="se-content">
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
        <p>LOL LOL LOL LOL </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="se-slope">
      <article class="se-content">
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <p>LOL LOL LOL LOL</p>
      </article>
    </div>

  </section>
</div>
```